# Find the probability function

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

> Find the probability function $f(x) = P(X = x)$

I have a few questions,

I could try to find $F(x) = P(X \le x)$, but I don't understand how to do this conceptually.

So the way I see it,

$A = \text{Range } X$ depends on how many balls are picked.

So what is a way to approach this? Can you also provide some conceptual understanding?

Comment: Hint : $P(X\leq x)=$ probability that all balls are $\leq x$...

Comment: Can you say how do you understand the definition of $X$ ? For me the definition is a little bit too vague.

Comment: $$P(X=x)=\frac{{x\choose n}-{x-1\choose n}}{{N\choose n}}$$

Answer (score -1):

For $X$, the largest number selected among $n$ balls, to be $x$, you must select ball numbered $x$, and $n-1$ from the $x-1$ balls which have smaller numbers.   The probability of doing this is what you seek.

Since you are selecting without replacement, $x$ cannot be smaller than $n$; giving you the support interval of $X\in\{n,\ldots, N\}$